# Why does minOccurs="0" cause null value

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd

I have a complex type in my xsd as following:

```
<xsd:complexType name="AddUserRequestType">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Header" type="tns:HeaderType" />
         <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Body">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Login" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CompanyId" nillable="true" type="xsd:int" />
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Surname" type="xsd:string" />      
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

The problem is whenever I set *minOccurs* property of *CompanyId* to zero, any incoming value from the client to my web service for *CompanyId* is seen as null. When I change *minOccurs* to 1 , any value sent by client can be received as is on the server side. So my question is how can I overcome this problem without setting *minOccurs* to 1 as I want to represent clients this element could potentially be null.

FYI, my web service is written in Java 1.6 , and  the client calling it is in C#

**UPDATE:**
Here is the client code:

```
            var httpClient = new ServiceReference1DemoServiceClient();
            var reqAddUser = new ServiceReference1.AddUserRequestType()
            {
                Header = new ServiceReference1.HeaderType {},
                Body = new ServiceReference1.AddUserRequestTypeBody()
                {
                    Login = "TestLogin",
                    CompanyId = 19,
                    Name = "TestName",
                    Surname = "TestSurname",

                }

            };

            ServiceReference1.AddUserResponseType resp = httpClient.AddUser(reqAddUser);
            Console.WriteLine(resp.Result.Error.Exists.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Is that value you get with `minOccurs = 1 ` any usefull or just the *empty string `""`? However, without seeing the clients code we cannot tell. the reason, only guess...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle see my update pls

Comment: This still does not answer my first question.

Comment: The element (CompanyId) could be null namely it's up to client to set it, so I set minOccurs to 0 to represent nullable feature and it's not string, but int as it's seen from xsd. Does this give answer your question? @TimothyTruckle

Comment: Did you check that the expected value is actually present in the XML when the element is set to `minOccurs = 0`?

Comment: Of course I did as client side code is also mine, so I send xml request from the client side to my service @TimothyTruckle